# Debug web add-in for outlook in visual studio code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, outlook-addin, bsconfig

I was following the tutorial for creating an advanced Outlook add-in [here (Git the Gist)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/addin-tutorial)

The above is a **node.js**-app which uses **Yeoman** and **Microsoft Office Add-in Project Generator**. To simply start the add-in, you just type 'npm start' in your root project folder.

But: I want to debug the add-in in **Visual Studio Code**.

VS Code automatically creates a `launch.json` file when you want to debug a project. This file looks like this:

```
 "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\bsconfig.json"
        }
    ]
```

However, when I debug I get the following error:

> Cannot launch program `'c:\ZTesting\outlooktest\bsconfig.json'`; setting
>   the `outFiles` attribute might help.

So are these `outFiles` truly the problem and - if so - what should they be?
And - if not - what is the solution towards debugging a web add-in created with **node.js**, **Yeoman** and **Microsoft Office Add-in Project Generator**?

The `bsconfig.json` file looks like this:

```
{
    "ui": {
        "port": 3000
    },
    "server": {
        "routes": {
            "/node_modules": "node_modules"
        }
    },
    "https": {
        "key": "./certs/server.key",
        "cert": "./certs/server.crt"
    },
    "watch": true,
    "files": "*.*"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I did not find out how to debug the add-in above in Visual Studio Code. However it is possible to debug the add-in with the F12-developer-app from Windows 10.

You can find more information about the F12-app here:
[Debug add ins using F12 Developer-app from Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10)

Comment: It seems like F12-app can't open outlook add-ins. Nothing happened when I click on the add-ins in F12-app

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem today.
However, there is a tricky way to debug your outlook add-ins if WIN10 F12-app not able to open your html file.

you can use tbody.append to show any value when you debug your add-ins in outlook

```
var tbody = $('.prop-table');
tbody.append(makeTableRow("asyncResult: ", item));
function makeTableRow(name, value) {
    return $("<tr><td><strong>" + name +
        "</strong></td><td class=\"prop-val\"><code>" +
        value + "</code></td></tr>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. The root cause is that the app does not actually run on the server. `npm start` actually runs a separate program, called webpack. You can see this by opening package.json. There should be a line like the following:

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --https --key ./certs/server.key --cert ./certs/server.crt --cacert ./certs/ca.crt --port 3000"
```

When you run `npm start`, [it adds node_modules/.bin/ to the path](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) before running that line. So this script is actually calling an executable called node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server. **Webpack does not run any of the code in index.js.** It "packs" the code, and broadcasts it over https to the client.

Since the app code only runs on the client, it can only be debugged on the client. The use of `npm start` makes it look like you're writing server code, but the add-in is actually running clientside.